# Binding MigLayout debug mode to the application's logging level?

Tags: java, swing, logging, debugging, miglayout

Debug mode in [MigLayout](http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/) is quite powerful option for development and debugging. It is declared by adding a keyword in layout constraints string:

```
new MigLayout("fill, hidemode 3, debug");
```

Well, it would be nice to bind MigLayout's debug mode to the logging level of the application. Something like:

```
MigLayout.setLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(MigLayout.class));
```

MigLayout's debug mode could be then switched on and off declarative, using logging configuration. Is this already possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
new MigLayout("fill, hidemode 3" + (LoggerFactory.getLogger(MigLayout.class).isLoggable(DEBUG) ? ", debug" : ""));
```